# How do I open new window passing control values MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to open a link in a new window using MVC 5 passing data in for my model

This is my approach now which works fine

```
@Html.ActionLink("Window Title", "Index", "Controller", new {title = "My Title", productType = "car"}, new {target = "_blank"})
```

However, if I was to have a product type text box (txtCar) which the user types into, how can I get txtCar's value into my model?

This is tricky as I know its kind of crossing the boundary between client and server

I think I may need to scrap this way and use Javascript, but I dont know how to open a link in a new window and create my model with Javascript?

Can someone help please?

I am using C# MVC 5

Cheers

Paul

Comment: you can pass the model itself which will contain the textbox if its strongly types

Comment: I don’t have a model for my view at the moment but isn’t the model only updated server side?

Comment: no when you pass the model to actionLink it will also contain the updated values

Comment: Ok I will see if I can add it to my model what is the syntax for passing the model in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Html.ActionLink("My Link Title", "MyAction", "MyController", null, new { onclick = "this.href += '&txtCar=' + document.getElementById('txtCar').value;" })
```

This is how can you pass the textbox value

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Lookup", "User", new { JSONModel = Json.Encode(Model) }, null)
```

This way you can pass model

Comment: What is myRouteValueName?  The first one is the one I want to use but no values are getting through to my controller's index method parameters?

Comment: Thanks the first one now works note that the & should be ? after href but its too small an edit!